# Getting Error while Creating a new React App from Terminal on NPM 6.14.4

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

While using the below command, I am getting a few errors.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

The errors I am getting can be seen below:

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...8olCMjOZDx5OzCM3r6Cqh'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\sid\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-31.......debug.log

Comment: tried npm cache clean --force but it warns and not implemented

Comment: remove node_moddules and package-lock.json after that, clear the cache again reinstall packages.